# Meaning of the word "findings"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, nouns

I need to find a word to define the products you see in the image below.
The best match I've found is *findings*.

Is this word the correct one? Is there a better word for these products?

[image: Three groups of bead-like objects ("bead" used in its loosest sense of "something with a hole drilled through it for a string"). The first group is labeled "Metal" and includes a gold hoop, a flat silver disk with a hole in the middle, a silver flattened oblong with no visible hole, a small brass disk with a hole in the middle, and a gold coin with a hole near the edge. The second group is labeled "Natural" and includes a bone oval cabochon, a bone asymmetrical triangular loop, a mother-of-pearl disk with a large hole in the middle, and a small dark round bead. The third group is labeled "Resin" and includes a silvery heart bead, a large flat dark amber-colored oval bead, a small clear round bead, an amber-colored pony bead, and a small cream-colored oval cabochon.]

Comment: may be you can use objects

Comment: These look like beads... What do you mean by **findings**? Where do you want to use the word? What context?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr In the context you see in the picture. It is a title for those products. Check this link: https://www.google.es/search?q=findings&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=es&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=806LUejcIJGDhQf1iYHIAg&biw=1440&bih=737&sei=9U6LUdPKHsiv0QXq3oHIDA#imgrc=_

Comment: Then ***beads*** is what I'd say after looking at the image. Findings are more than just these, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finding and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bead

Comment: In fact, per Wikipedia, *findings* are specifically **not** these objects.

Comment: This question feels like a Rorschach test

Comment: I'd like to be able to access the original diagram. I feel sure that 'metal', 'natural' and 'resin' should be categories within 'findings' rather than, as the OP's version suggests, categories other than 'findings'. Not that I think that more than one of the objects could possibly be called 'findings' anyway.

Comment: In the crafting world, those objects are known as findings.  And, as @EdwinAshworth suggested, they can be further classified by their material into "metal findings", "natural findings", "resin findings", etc.

Comment: I'd call these *beads*, except that each group contains one item that is clearly **not** a bead because it has no hole in it. "Beads and cabochons"? That's not a particularly satisfying category name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jewelry "findings" are the parts used to join jewellery components together to form a completed article... 
As @Fr0zenFyr mentioned refer this article: 
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finding

Comment: for reference, there is an entire website for buying findings online :
http://www.jewelryfindings-online.com/ON%20LINE%20CATALOG.asp

look under the findings sub-category

Comment: I'd say that '(costume) jewellery components' covers all the objects shown - they mainly seem to be 'jewellery non-findings' if anything.

Answer (score 0):

"Results" perhaps, if these are displayed after someone has searched.

Comment: It in not a search listing result.